# Are there any explanations for the fantastical elements of the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

In the matrix movies, there are several fantasy elements as well:

- The Oracle predicting the future
- Limbo (or whatever the railway station at the start of the third movie was called)

Were there any explanations for these given in the movie? Are there any explanations consistent with the story?

Comment: Cool question.  I'd nominate, as the most fantastical: how was Neo able to do inhuman things *outside* of the Matrix, in the third movie?  Anything within the Matrix can be explained as part of the program.

Comment: @Jon of All Trades:I think they officially explain it off by saying his mind is liked to the matrix even without the link.

Comment: I like the "real world is another level of the Matrix" explanation myself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the major resolutions at the end of the Matrix is that the external world is also part of the plan. Some think this means that the external world is not real, that it is also a matrix. This would clear up the problems you see, as these sub-worlds are all still entirely digital.

Others take it to mean that what happens in the real world is part of the plan but is still real. In this case, the fact that everything has occurred several times, gives the Oracle data to draw from. She knows, because she's seen it at least 8 other times.

Limbo is harder to deal with if the real world really is real. However, leaving one's own body and becoming purely digital (which Neo did when going to Limbo) is possible. That same ability is what let Smith enter the real world.

What I find impossible to deal with reasonably is how Neo could see the machines outside the Matrix and exert control over them. This is why I tend to subscribe to the idea that the real world is a sub-matrix.

Comment: or the "real world" is a rendered interpretation of a digital representation of the real world

Comment: @Xantec, that's what my first paragraph says.

Comment: Neo could see the machines outside the Matrix because he (his brain) was still connected Matrix. As machines were part of Matrix in real world, his connection allowed him to stop them, sense them.

Answer (score 18):

The Oracle was a very advanced AI capable of mathematically calculating the results of present actions on the future, in other words predicting the future.

If I remember correctly, the Limbo was in fact the area between the Machine "Homeland" and the Matrix. People passing between the two have to go through it, like those AIs that wanted to escape to the Matrix with their daughter.

Comment: But the Oracle makes some very precise predictions, which require her to predict not only human and machine choices in the matrix,  but to also predict human behaviour outside the matrix.

Comment: This is a very believable hypothetical. If, in today's world, tech companies have algorithms that can predict consumer patterns, it makes sense that a computer capable of sentient thought would be able to expand such algorithms to predict human patterns (behavior).

Comment: If you take the determinist view of the universe, then *everything* is predictable if you have the right math.

Comment: [Psychohistory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychohistory_%28fictional%29) anyone?

Comment: To paraphrase: "What'll really bake your noodle is if you would've knocked it over if I hadn't said anything." Surely the machine AI is advanced enough to understand the power of suggestion over the human mind.

Answer (score 1):

For the Oracle there is a real limit to what she can see. She tries to explain this limit by saying "We can never see past the choices we don't understand" explaining that we Neo had already made the choice. This would lead to a certain level of predetermination (fate) existing that allows her to see what has not yet happened, because she already knows what choices have/will be made.
The Limbo is simply a Matrix like environment that is a passage between the machine world and the Matrix. The fantastical element is that Neo is able to have his conciousness separate from his body without a physical link up. Think of it as WiFi instead of a wired modem.
Now the actions outside of the Matrix in the "Real World" are the hardest sell. Again it has to go back to the separation of mind and body and you have to take a leap of fate that his mind is in someway partially connected to the Machine World. This would allow him to get sensory perception externally but him being able to stop the "squiddies" with his mind, well you need to beleive his mind is so powerful that it can create a local EMP wave. Both the separation and the EMP wave are fantastical but do have a possible explanation that requires you to beleive that Neo was in fact an unique human being that has a unique brian/mind that allows him to be part man part program.